# Weird txt behavior

Tags: shell, github, centos, cat

I have a centos server. I cloned a GitHub repository. And I have .txt file in that repository which contains 1 line. For some reason it does that:

```
[root@0-0-0-0 Some]# cat some.txt
some text[root@0-0-0-0 Some]#
```

And also `while read i; do echo "$i"; done < some.txt` don't see that line. What could cause that? And how to avoid it. If I edit it with vim adding a new line and then deleting that new line (so it still contains only one line) it starts to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text file has no newline character at the end of it. Some programs will treat it as a valid text file whose last line doesn't happen to end in a newline. Others (apparently including bash's built-in `read` command, at least by default) will treat it as invalid, and perhaps ignore the last line (which isn't considered a "line" because it's not marked as one).

vim's default behavior is to quietly add a newline to the end of a file if you modify and save it.

You can add a newline to a file that lacks one by editing it with vim (or another editor that behaves similarly), or by adding it from the shell:

```
echo '' >> some.txt
```

In general, it's a good idea to ensure that text files end in a newline character in the first place, at least if they're intended to be used on UNIX-like systems.

Comment: `read` ignoring the last line when it isn't terminated with a newline character is the reason for the ugly `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]];` to guarantee reading all lines.